# Sending multiple Goals to robot by cpp code

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, 2d-nav-goal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

after testing the sending a simpleGoal to my robot i based on http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals and it working  well
i focus now  on sending multiple goals  when it reached the first one go to the second one ...
it's possible   if yes  help with documentations or example
NB: i am programming with cpp :)

Update:

i tried with this  what do you think about it

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <move_base_msgs/MoveBaseAction.h>
#include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>

typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> MoveBaseClient;


bool one_move(move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal goal) {
  goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "base_link";
  goal.target_pose.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

      ac.sendGoal(goal);
      ac.waitForResult();
      if(ac.getState() == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::SUCCEEDED)
           return true;
      else
           return false;
        }



int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "simple_navigation_goals");

  //tell the action client that we want to spin a thread by default
  MoveBaseClient ac("move_base", true);

  //wait for the action server to come up
  while(!ac.waitForServer(ros::Duration(5.0))){
    ROS_INFO("Waiting for the move_base action server to come up");
  }

  move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal goal[3];


  goal[0].target_pose.pose.position.x = 0.7783;
  goal[0].target_pose.pose.position.y = -0.0390;
  goal[0].target_pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;

  goal[0].target_pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
  goal[0].target_pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
  goal[0].target_pose.pose.orientation.z = 0.0182;
  goal[0].target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 0.99910;

  goal[1].target_pose.pose.position.x = 0.7783;
  goal[1].target_pose.pose.position.y = -0.0390;
  goal[1].target_pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;

  goal[1].target_pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
  goal[1].target_pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
  goal[1].target_pose.pose.orientation.z = 0.0182;
  goal[1].target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 0.99910;
  
  goal[2].target_pose.pose.position.x = 0.7783;
  goal[2].target_pose.pose.position.y = -0.0390;
  goal[2].target_pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;

  goal[2].target_pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
  goal[2].target_pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
  goal[2].target_pose.pose.orientation.z = 0.0182;
  goal[2].target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 0.99910;

  //we'll send a goal to the robot to move 1 meter forward
 

 ROS_INFO("Sending goal1");
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
 {
    if(one_move(goal[i])
     {
      ROS_INFO("Hooray, the %f goal reached",i);
     }
    else 
   {
      ROS_INFO("The the %f goal doesn't reached for some reason",i)
   return 0;
  }     
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285431/sending-multiple-goals-to-robot-by-cpp-code/) by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well I think that there are 2 main problems in your code:

1. There is a redundancy in the instructions,  and if you will once need to send more than 2 goals , say 5 or even 10 you'll get a huge code for no reason.
2. Your code doesn't care if the robot didn't succeed the first goal  and passes to the second one anyway.

A better practice would be to:

```
//create a function taking care about reaching one goal and returning true if it succeed
bool one_move(goal) {
      ...
      ac.sendGoal(goal);
      ac.waitForResult();
      if(ac.getState() == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::SUCCEEDED)
           return true;
      else
           return false;
        }
                    
int main(int argc, char** argv){
       ...
     //define  a list of goals
     //loop over the entered goals and pass to the next goal if OK or break if not.
      ...
     return 0;
        }
```

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) with karma: 188 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on 2018-03-15**:
thank you very much :)

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2018-03-15**:
You're welcome!

**Comment by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on 2018-03-15**:
i modified the code have a look ;)

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2018-03-19**:
Theoretically, that's it but, did you try to compile the node and run it. There are some obvious errors like in `bool one_move(goal) {` , it is needed to specify the input type of the function etc. You need to succeed the compilation and see the output result to know if something is going wrong.

**Comment by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on 2018-03-20**:
yeah i see i made the modifications requires now works well thank you very much :)

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2018-03-20**:
Happy to help!

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-06**:
what is the final answer?

**Comment by [Joseph444](https://answers.ros.org/users/55898/joseph444/) on 2020-06-19**:
Hello, is it possible if I could see the revised? I've been trying for days to find a way to make a square or circular path using multiple goals in cpp.

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2020-06-19**:
Hi, can you be more precise or share your progress so we can help you better?